# Python Struct, size changed by alignment.

Tags: python, struct

Here's the hex code I am trying to unpack.
b'ABCDFGHa\x00a\x00a\x00a\x00a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01' (it's not supposed to make any sense)

```
labels = unpack('BBBBBBBHHHHH5sB', msg)
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes argument of length 24
```

From what I counted, both of those are length = 23, both the format in my unpack function and the length of the hex values. I don't understand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Most processors access data faster when the data is on natural boundaries, meaning data of size 2 should be on even addresses, data of size 4 should be accessed on addresses divisible by four, etc.

`struct` by default maintains this alignment.  Since your structure starts out with 7 'B', a padding byte is added to align the next 'H' on an even address.  To prevent this in Python, precede your string with '='.

#### Example:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize('BBB')
3
>>> struct.calcsize('BBBH')
6
>>> struct.calcsize('=BBBH')
5
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `H` is enforcing 2-byte alignment after your 7 `B`

Aha, the alignment info is at the top of http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html, not down by [the definition of the format characters](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters).