# Issue with sending data through socket

Tags: python, sockets

Hwy, I am working on socket in python and try to send data from between 2 application through sockets

Here is the sender code :

```
import socket
import struct
import time

RECEIVER_IP = "localhost"
RECEIVER_PORT = 17781

class gps_packet:
    def __init__(self, latitude, latitude_indicator, longitude, longitude_indicator,
                 dilution_of_precision, horizontal_dilution_of_precision, vertical_dilution_of_precision):
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.latitude_indicator = 1 if latitude_indicator == 'N' else -1
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.longitude_indicator = 1 if longitude_indicator == 'E' else -1
        self.dilution_of_precision = dilution_of_precision
        self.horizontal_dilution_of_precision = horizontal_dilution_of_precision
        self.vertical_dilution_of_precision = vertical_dilution_of_precision


def create_udp_socket():
    try:
        sockfd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        return sockfd
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Failed to create sender socket:", e)
        return None

def send_gps_data(sockfd, gps_data):
    try:
        payload = struct.pack('dbdbddd', gps_data.latitude, gps_data.latitude_indicator, gps_data.longitude, gps_data.longitude_indicator,gps_data.dilution_of_precision, gps_data.horizontal_dilution_of_precision, gps_data.vertical_dilution_of_precision)
        base_packet = struct.pack('IILQ', 277, 10220, 0, 0)  # Message ID, Message Length, Base Packet
        message = base_packet + payload
        # print(message)
        sockfd.sendto(message, (RECEIVER_IP, RECEIVER_PORT))
        print("GPS data sent successfully")
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Failed to send GPS data:", e)

def main():
    sockfd = create_udp_socket()
    if not sockfd:
        return

    # Example GPS data
    gps_data = gps_packet(latitude=37.7749, latitude_indicator='N',
                          longitude=-122.4194, longitude_indicator='W',
                          dilution_of_precision=1.2, horizontal_dilution_of_precision=1.5,
                          vertical_dilution_of_precision=1.8)

    while True:
        send_gps_data(sockfd, gps_data)
        time.sleep(1)  # Send data every 1 second

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And below is receiver code :

```
import socket
import struct

RECEIVER_PORT = 17781
BASE_PACKET_PAYLOAD_SIZE = 10096


class BasePacket:
    def __init__(self, crc32, count, version, timestamp, payload):
        self.crc32 = crc32
        self.count = count
        self.version = version
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.payload = payload


class PDUMessage:
    def __init__(self, messageID, messageLength, basePacket):
        self.messageID = messageID
        self.messageLength = messageLength
        self.basePacket = basePacket


class gps_packet:
    def __init__(self, latitude, latitude_indicator, longitude, longitude_indicator,
                 dilution_of_precision, horizontal_dilution_of_precision, vertical_dilution_of_precision):
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.latitude_indicator = latitude_indicator
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.longitude_indicator = longitude_indicator
        self.dilution_of_precision = dilution_of_precision
        self.horizontal_dilution_of_precision = horizontal_dilution_of_precision
        self.vertical_dilution_of_precision = vertical_dilution_of_precision


def create_udp_socket():
    try:
        sockfd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        print("Receiver socket opened")
        return sockfd
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Failed to create receiver socket:", e)
        return None


def bind_socket(sockfd, port):
    try:
        sockfd.bind(("", port))
        print("Socket bound successfully")
        return True
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Failed to bind socket:", e)
        return False


def receive_data(sockfd):
    try:
        data, sender_addr = sockfd.recvfrom(4096)
        # Ensure the received data is at least 24 bytes before unpacking
        if len(data) < 24:
            print("Received data too short:", len(data), "bytes")
            return None, None
        
            
        received_message = struct.unpack('IILQ', data[:20])  # Unpack the fixed part of the message
        payload = struct.unpack('10096s', data[20:])[0]  # Unpack the payload
        received_message = PDUMessage(received_message[0], received_message[1],
                                    BasePacket(received_message[2], received_message[3], received_message[4],
                                                received_message[5], payload))
        return received_message, sender_addr
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Failed to receive data:", e)
        return None, None


def get_gps_data(sockfd):
    while True:
        print("data thread")
        received_message, sender_addr = receive_data(sockfd)
        # print(received_message)

        if received_message.messageID == 277:
            recv_packet = gps_packet(*struct.unpack('dbdbddd', received_message.basePacket.payload))

            print("Received data from IP:", sender_addr[0])
            print(recv_packet.horizontal_dilution_of_precision)
            print("data received successfully")


def main():
    sockfd = create_udp_socket()
    if not sockfd:
        return

    if not bind_socket(sockfd, RECEIVER_PORT):
        sockfd.close()
        return

    get_gps_data(sockfd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now when I start the sender code it working fine but at the receiver code the terminal shows below error and related error

```
Receiver socket opened
Socket bound successfully
data thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jangoo/Map_Optimize/./reciever_socket_2.py", line 103, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jangoo/Map_Optimize/./reciever_socket_2.py", line 99, in main
    get_gps_data(sockfd)
  File "/home/jangoo/Map_Optimize/./reciever_socket_2.py", line 79, in get_gps_data
    received_message, sender_addr = receive_data(sockfd)
  File "/home/jangoo/Map_Optimize/./reciever_socket_2.py", line 65, in receive_data
    received_message = struct.unpack('IILQ', data[:20])  # Unpack the fixed part of the message
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 24 bytes
```

Now I am stuck at it, I want to have the data transfer between 2 applications.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: As said, either slice at 24 or change the format. The payload handling seems wrong too: you `pack('dbdbddd', ...)` which is 56 bytes but `struct.unpack('10096s', ...)` which is 10096 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to sockets. You specify a buffer of 20 bytes (`data[:20]`) yet you ask to extract 24 bytes from it (`struct.unpack('IILQ',...`), hence

> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 24 bytes

But, doesn't [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) claim that it should be 20 bytes in total, i.e. 4 bytes for `I`, 4 bytes for `L` and 8 bytes for `Q`?

This is only true for *"standard"* encoding, which need to be explicitly enforced using the `=` prefix (or `<` or `>`), i.e. `=IILQ` instead of `IILQ`. Without a prefix enforcing standard encoding it will be native encoding, which is likely 8 byte for `L` on your system.

Comment: Its not encoding, [but alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110378/python-struct-size-changed-by-alignment). Manual padding would be `"=IILxxxxQ"`.

Comment: @ivvija: it's encoding - try `struct.pack('L',0x0102030405060708)` and observe that all of the 8 bytes actually end up in the response  -> `b'\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01'`. This means `L` is taking the full 8 bytes. Also, why would the native alignment for  a 4 byte `I` be at 4 byte while for a presumably 4 byte `L` at 8 byte?

Comment: Ok, so it can be both. On my PC (Win11) that fails `struct.error: argument out of range` (3.9) / `struct.error: 'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295` (3.12). The `Q` gets aligned to multiples of 8 and padding is inserted before it, try `struct.pack('BQ',0xFF, 0x0102030405060708)`